# How to filter specific words in Kibana (Elastic)

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, kibana

For ease of access I use Kibana (web interface) for Elastic Search.
I have these 4 types of sentences in each line in random order which is repeating:

> N'Some Name' was looking for P'Some Name'.
>
> N'Some Name' was looking for N'Some Name'.
>
> P'Some Name' was looking for N'Some Name'.
>
> P'Some Name' was looking for P'Some Name'.

I'm trying to filter just first and last letter. For example I'd like to see records of letter which begins with **P'** and ends with **N'**. Then I'll try this query:

```
"^P*" AND "was looking for" AND "N$*"
```

But it gives me no results. I think there's something wrong because between *P'* and *Some Name* is not space and I can't figure out how to filter just **P'** and after **N'**.

Even when I try to NO filter exact position (^ = begins, $ = ends) like this it gives me no result:

```
"P*" AND "was looking for" AND "N*"
```

So result of this should look like:

> *P'Some Name' was looking for N'Some Name'.*
>
> or
>
> *N'Some Name' was looking for P'Some Name'.*

(because there's not excactly said that "P*" is first and "N*" is last - this means 2 results.)

Could you help me please how to make exact query which filters N' or P' on exact position?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your sentence :- P'Some Name' was looking for N'Some Name'.

Kindly use the following mentioned search query

> /P*/ AND "was looking for" AND /N*/